# Python checking in a list towards a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to retrieve the values in `specs` for the names in `names`. For example retrieving the `eye` value for all the entries in the `name` list based on the `specs`.

```
name=['john', 'tom', 'carry']


specs=[{'name': 'john', 'eye': 'blue' },{'name': 'tom', 'eye': 'green', 'hair': 'long' }, {'name': 'carry', 'eye': 'grey', 'hair': 'short', 'height': 'short'}, {'name': 'peter', 'eye': 'blue' } ]
```

This is the code I have managed to write and it print out `eye` values for all the elements, however I only want the elements that are in the `name` list.

```
  for d in specs:
        print (d['eye'])
```

Comment: You may want to turn `names` into a `set` instead of a `list` to make this more efficient (at least based on the answers). Though with only three names it is not that big of deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the value in the `name` key in the dictionary, to see if it is in `names` like this:

```
for d in specs:
    if d['name'] in names:
        print(d['eye'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for d in specs:
    if d['name'] in name:
        print (d['eye'])
```

There's no need to do any additional loops, all you need is a filter so that you only print out the information thats needed, and we filter the output using an `if` statement.

The `if` statement justs checks if the value of `d['name']` is in the array `name`, more simply; if the corresponding name to the specs is in `name = [....]`

Comment: can you please add some explanation, so it will be easy to understand.

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde hopefully thats better

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in specs:
    if d['name'] in name:
        print (d['eye'])
```

Add a filter before your print.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for d in specs:
    if d['name'] in name:
        print(d['eye'])
```

Answer (score 0):

no repetition eyes

```py
list({i['eye'] for i in specs if i['name'] in set(name)})
```